# use psycopg with installed PostgreSQL Database

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I would like to get started with working with python and PSQL databases.
The script I have in mind will (at least not at the beginning) run on hosts with an installed PSQL Database, but I want the script to connect remotely to the database.

In fact (for the start):

user hosts: run the script (read xls, convert, manipulate, etc) and write into remote DB
DB Host: this will host the db and gets connections from the user hosts and the "Sync Host"
Sync Host: a cloud service which will connect to the db server to read the databases and do some "magic" with it.

from what I have read, the best python module for PSQL connection is psycopg, but this seems to require an installed PSQL Database, which is something I do not have (and don't want to install) on the user hosts.

At a later stage I will remove the "user hosts" and provide a webinterface for uploading the xls and do the conversion, etc on the db host, but for the beginning I wanted to start as mentioned above.

My questions:

Is my thinking totally wrong? should I start with a central approach (webinterface, etc) right awa

If not, how can I get a PSQL connection method implemented in python without installing a PSQL Database?

All User hosts are Mac OS X, so Python is already installed.

thanks a lot in advance

Andre

Comment: You do *not* need to have postgres installed on the machine to use `psycopg2`. You specify the host when connecting.

Comment: @That1Guy OK, can you explain how to install psycopg2 without the required PSQL ninaries and conf files? Building it requires  pg_config

Comment: You should just be able to `sudo pip install psycopg2`. I believe `libpq-dev` is also a requirement. (It has been a while since I've installed this)

Comment: @That1Guy this is exactly what I meant. It requires some PQSL libraries so it's not really "plattform independent" anymore. I was looking for something which does not need such "low level" libraries.

Comment: Then you phrased your question wrong: `how can I get a PSQL connection method implemented in python without installing a PSQL Database?`. `libpq-dev` is **not** a database.